# Coil placeholder not showing if vectorpainter is used in jetpack compose

Tags: image, android-jetpack-compose, placeholder, image-loading, coil

I am using the following code to display an image.

```kotlin
       AsyncImage(
               model = createImageUrl(audio.image_path),
                   contentDescription = "Song Artwork",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                                       .aspectRatio(1f)
                                       .padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
                    placeholder = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Outlined.MusicNote)
                )
```

The placeholder image is not being shown. Howeve, if I use placeHolder = painterResource(R.drawable.someDrawableInMyResource), the drawable is being shown when image is loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

```kotlin
var loaded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    AsyncImage(
        model = createImageUrl(audio.image_path),
        contentDescription = "Song Artwork",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().aspectRatio(1f).padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
        placeholder = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.MusicNote),
        error = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.MusicNote),
        fallback = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.MusicNote),
        onSuccess = {
            loaded = true
        },
        colorFilter = if (!loaded) ColorFilter.tint(LocalContentColor.current) else null
    )
```

I used this workaround and this works. I am open for another clean suggestions.

Comment: For anybody stuck on the problem, I found the solution in coil docs. https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/recipes/#transforming-painters.. The idea is to wrap error-painter with forwardingPainter with tint provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. I was in dark theme and the image vector`s tint color matched my background and thus nothing was being shown.

May help someone.

Edit: Well my question changed.. How to change placeholder tint to match my theme?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).